# Converting FindRoot minimization to NMinimze

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have the following orbital insertion simulation that uses a linear-tangent steering law and the `FindRoot` function to find the parameters $\theta_{0}$ and $\theta_{f}$ that allow the lunar ascent vehicle to reach a stable orbit about the Moon once its APS engine is turned off:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
G = 6.672*10^-11 ;(*Gravitational constant*)
M = 7.3476*10^22; (*kg*)(*Mass of Moon*)
R = 1737*10^3; (*m*)(*Radius of Moon*)
g = 9.81; (*m/s^2*)(*Gravitational acceleration on Earth, used for Isp*)
mprop = 2353;(*kg*)(*APS propellant mass*)
mstruct = 2150;(*kg*)(*Lunar ascent stage structural mass*) 
T = 16000 ;(*N*)(*APS thurst*)
Isp = 311;(*Specific impulse*)
mdot = T/(g Isp);(*kg/s*)(*APS mass flow rate*)
tburn = mprop/mdot (*seconds*)(*Maximum available engine burn time*)
mtotal = mprop + mstruct; (*kg*)(*Total mass of propellant and structure*)

x0 = 0; (*m*)(*Initial x-position*)
y0 = R; (*m*)(*Initial y-position*)
vx0 = 0; (*m/s*)(*Initial x-velocity*)
vy0 = 0; (*m/s*)(*Initial y-velocity*)


F = If[t < tburn, T, 0]; (*Thrust turns off after tburn*)
\[Theta][t_] := ArcTan[Tan[\[Theta]0] - (Tan[\[Theta]0] - Tan[\[Theta]f]) t/tburn]; (*Linear-Tangent Steering law*)

tmax = 10000; (*seconds*)(*Maximum simulation running time*)
LTS = ParametricNDSolve[{
    x'[t] == vx[t],
    y'[t] == vy[t],
    r'[t] == D[Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], t],
    vx'[t] == F/m[t] Cos[\[Theta][t]] - (G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2),
    vy'[t] == F/m[t] Sin[\[Theta][t]] - (G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2),
    m'[t] == -F/(g Isp),
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, r[0] == Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2], vx[0] == vx0, 
    vy[0] == vy0, m[0] == mtotal}, {x[t], y[t], vx[t], vy[t], m[t], 
    r[t], r'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f}];

rorbit = R + 100000;(*m*)(*Desired orbit of 100km above the surface of the Moon*)

vorbit = Sqrt[(G M)/rorbit](*m/s*)(*Velocity needed to attain a circular orbit at rorbit*)

(*Root finder algorithm used to enforce constraints when the \
spacecraft's engine turns off at time t = tf*)
LTSSolution = FindRoot[{r[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f] == rorbit, r'[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f] == 0, Sqrt[(vx[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2 + (vy[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2] == vorbit} /. 
   LTS, {{t, 0.9 tburn, 0.1 tburn, tburn}, {\[Theta]0, 50 Degree, 0 Degree, 89 Degree}, {\[Theta]f, -20 Degree, -50 Degree, -10 Degree}}]
\[Theta]0 = LTSSolution[[2]][[2]](*radians*)(*Initial thrust angle*)
\[Theta]f = LTSSolution[[3]][[2]](*radians*)(*Final thrust angle*)
tf = LTSSolution[[1]][[2]](*seconds*)(*Engine cut-off time*)

(*Plots*)
AscentOrbit = 
 ParametricPlot[{x[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f], y[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f]} /. LTS, {t, 0, tf}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
vradial = Plot[{r'[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f]} /. LTS, {t, 0, tf}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "v_radial(t)"}]
v = Plot[Sqrt[(vx[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2 + (vy[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2] /. LTS, {t, 0, tf}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "v(t)"}]
m = Plot[{m[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f]} /. LTS, {t, 0, tf}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "m(t)"}]

\[Theta][t_] := 
 ArcTan[Tan[\[Theta]0] - (Tan[\[Theta]0] - Tan[\[Theta]f]) t/tburn]; (*Linear-Tangent Steering law*)
F = If[t < tf, T, 0]; (*Thrust turns off after tburn*)

Orbit = NDSolve[{
   x'[t] == vx[t],
   y'[t] == vy[t],
   r'[t] == D[Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], t],
   vx'[t] == F/m[t] Cos[\[Theta][t]] - (G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2),
   vy'[t] == F/m[t] Sin[\[Theta][t]] - (G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2),
   m'[t] == -(F/(g Isp)),
   x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, r[0] == Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2], vx[0] == vx0, 
   vy[0] == vy0, m[0] == mtotal}, {x[t], y[t], vx[t], vy[t], 
   m[t], \[Gamma][t], r[t], r'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]


(*Plots*)
FullOrbit = 
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. Orbit, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
vradial = Plot[{r'} /. Orbit, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "v_radial(t)"}]
v = Plot[Sqrt[(vx[t])^2 + (vy[t])^2] /. Orbit, {t, 0, 0.1 tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "v(t)"}]
m = Plot[{m[t]} /. Orbit, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "m(t)"}]

(*Trajectory animation*)
Animate[Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. Orbit], {t, 0, a}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotStyle -> Automatic], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, R]}]], {a, 0, tmax}, AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

However, `FindRoot` is very sensitive to initial guess values, and as such I wanted to try and use a global minimizer such as `NMinimize` instead. I tried replacing the `FindRoot` code with the following `NMinimize` code, but I am unfortunately getting errors:

```
LTSSolution = NMinimize[{Abs[r[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f] - rorbit] + Abs[r'[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f] - 0] + Abs[Sqrt[(vx[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2 + (vy[t][\[Theta]0, \[Theta]f])^2] - vorbit]} /.LTS, {{t, 0.9 tburn, 0.1 tburn, tburn}, {\[Theta]0, 50 Degree, 0 Degree, 89 Degree}, {\[Theta]f, -20 Degree, -50 Degree, -10 Degree}}, Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

With the following error:

```
"Variables {{t,403.807,44.8674,448.674},{\[Theta]0,50\ \[Degree],0,89\
\ \[Degree]},{\[Theta]f,-20\ \[Degree],-50\ \[Degree],-10\ \
\[Degree]}} should be a list of variables, with each element being a \
variable, or a list containing a variable and lower and upper bounds \
for the starting region for that variable"
```

Would anyone possibly know why the above approach using `NMinimize` is giving me errors?

Attached are images of the position, radial velocity and final orbit respectively:
[image][image][image]

Comment: `WhenEvent[]` might be a better strategy...

Comment: Hmmm, I'm a bit confused, how would I use `WhenEvent[]` to perform parameter optimization?

Comment: You can use it to check when the derivative becomes zero. Of course, you still need to pick minima out afterwards.